# Windows phone Textual app

Tags: fonts, windows-phone

I am developing a basic textual windows phone app. It consists of a Main page and few other pages that branch from it. I need 2 things mainly

1. Change the font in all the text pages from the settings page in the app.
2. Does xaml have tags like html where one can navigate to a different part/element in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

C# Code Behind:

```
this.textBlock.FontSize = 30;
this.textBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial"); //to be pulled from isolated storage
this.textBlock.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="TextBlock" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Arial" x:Name="textBlock"/>
```

As far as making the font cascade across the app, you could could use a single isolated storage value and change the text value (i.e. "Arial", "Tahoma", etc.) from your settings page in the app.

If this isn't clear enough I can code up a working sample for you.

More Samples: [Here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Windows-Phone-Beginners-How-to-Programmatically-set-common-Control-properties)